# toggle className using flag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flags, classname

```
const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false)

let visibleActive, visibleTransition

const handleSelect = () => {
    setFlag(!flag)
    visibleActive = flag ? 'visible active' : ''
    visibleTransition = flag ? 'visible transition' : ''
    console.log(flag)
    console.log(visibleActive)
    console.log(visibleTransition)
}

return (
    <>
        <div className="ui form">
            <div className="field">
                <label className="label">Select a color</label>
                <div className={`ui selection dropdown ${visibleActive}`} onClick={handleSelect}>
                    <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
                    <div className="text">Select Color</div>
                    <div className={`menu ${visibleTransition}`}>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </>
)
```

classes don't toggle when I click on the dropdown. I see the results in the console but the same is not applying on the JSX. The variables 'visibleTransition' and 'visibleActive' have the correct values but still these values are not being applied.

Comment: You can't store persisting values in plain variables, when the component is rendered after `setFlag()` the variables are redeclared and lose any value you assigned to them in the previous render cycle

Comment: Okay, so it should work if I declare those variables outside the functional component, right ?

Comment: It will work but if you declare it outside, those variables won't be removed from memory when the component unmounts. It will also cause issues if you have more than one instance of the same component.

Comment: @Shan How do I solve that issue. I want to remove the variables from memory as soon as the component is unmounted

Comment: @RishabhGupta check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React setState calls are batched and enqueued and state updates [may be async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). You cannot access the `flag` state immediately after setting it.

The `visibleActive`, `visibleTransition` variables will loose their values after re-render. You can use `useRef` to maintain a value between re-renders.

```
import {useRef} from 'react'

const visibleActive = useRef("")
const visibleTransition = useRef("")
```

You can assign a value to ref like `visibleActive.current = flag ? "visible active" : "";`

and Use `useEffect` to get the correct `flag` state value

```
useEffect(() => {
  visibleActive.current = flag ? "visible active" : "";
  visibleTransition.current = flag ? "visible transition" : "";
  console.log(flag);
  console.log(visibleActive);
  console.log(visibleTransition);
}, [flag]);
```

Comment: I don't think this works because the variables are declared as const and also as pointed out by @pilchard, the variable values get reinitialized after every re-render

Comment: these are not normal variables, `useRef` is a hook from react. It will return an object with current property,  notice that im using `visibleActive.current` to assign the value. `useRef` will be initialized once and will maintain the same reference between re-renders.

Comment: It works when I use ${visibleActive.current} in the className. Do I need to use '.current' everytime I want to acces the variables value ?

Comment: Yeah `.current` property is storing your value, need to use `visibleActive.current` everytime to access the value.